# Проверить на js существование Cookie

Tags: javascript

Появилась задача проверить существование COOKIE на стороне клиента, если существует, предоставить доступ{Вопрос закрыт}

Comment: Добавьте код пожалуйста, что бы была возможность видеть ваши попытки и сразу же помочь вам разобратся.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// возвращает cookie с именем name, если есть, если нет, то undefined
function getCookie(name) {
  let matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp(
    "(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"
  ));
  return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : undefined;
}
```

Взято от [сюда](https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie)

Answer (score 1):

Cкрипт, суть которого в том, чтобы он проверял наличие куков у пользователя. Если их нет, то ничего не происходит, если они есть и их значение "yes", то выполняется действие. Источник: [тык](https://javascript.ru/forum/events/34111-sozdanie-i-proverka-cookie.html)

```js
function setcookie(a,b,c) {if(c){var d = new Date();d.setDate(d.getDate()+c);}if(a && b) document.cookie = a+'='+b+(c ? '; expires='+d.toUTCString() : '');else return false;}
function getcookie(a) {var b = new RegExp(a+'=([^;]){1,}');var c = b.exec(document.cookie);if(c) c = c[0].split('=');else return false;return c[1] ? c[1] : false;}

setcookie("block","yes",10) //Cтавим кук (10 - число действующих дней

var block = getcookie( "block" );

   if ( block != "yes")
  {
    alert('TEST');
  }
  else
  {
    $("#errorbody").show("fast");
  }
```